# What verb to use with Only

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, verbs, subject-verb-agreement, compounds

Which sentence is correct? Which verb should I use when **only** is present at the beginning of the sentence?

> 1. Only me and Alia was there
> 2. Only me and Alia were there

Comment: There were two of you. _Only Alia and I were there._ It makes no difference whether _only_ is included or not. (It's considered correct to put yourself last in a list of people, and you wouldn't say _me was there_.)

Comment: Neither are correct! "Me" is not used as a subject. "I was there," not "Me was there."